# Como fazer com que o botão ocupe toda a altura e largura do seu elemento pai?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Olá.

Tenho uma tabela que é preenchida dinamicamente com dados vindo do banco MySQL. Para isso utilizo AJAX e PHP.

Eu tenho a seguinte dúvida: 
Como faço para que um botão (que na verdade é um  com classes que lhe dão características de button) ocupe toda a altura e largura da  que ele está dentro.

Por enquanto está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que eu gostaria que aquele botão "ALTERAR" preenchesse todo o espaço do  que ele está dentro.

**Segue abaixo o código de criação dessa Tabela:**

```js
function preencher_funcionarios() {
  $.ajax({
    //dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "banco/banco-vision/pagina-cadastrar-funcionarios/preencher-funcionarios.php",
    cache: false,

  }).done(function(data) {
    var funcionarios = "";

    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, func) {
      //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 

      funcionarios += '<tr id="' + func.codigo + '">';

      funcionarios += '<td>' + func.imagem + '</td>';
      funcionarios += '<td>' + func.usuario + '</td>';
      funcionarios += '<td>' + func.EMPRESA_ORIGEM + '</td>';
      funcionarios += '<td>' + func.departamento + '</td>';
      funcionarios += '<td>' + func.email + '</td>';
      funcionarios += '<td style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn btn-md btn-success" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-alterar-funcionarios">ALTERAR</a></td>';

      funcionarios += '</tr>';

    });

    $('#registros-funcionarios-cadastrados').html(funcionarios);


  }).fail(function() {
    alert('Falha na listagem dos usuários');

  }).always(function() {

  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(4, 27, 29, 1)100%, rgba(64, 64, 64) 100%);
  color: rgb(255, 250, 240);
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#row-filtros-funcionario {
  margin-top: 0%;
  color: rgba(211, 211, 211);
}

div#div-titulo-funcionarios h2 {
  color: GhostWhite;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: roboto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

div#formulario-alterar-funcionarios {
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div#listagem-funcionarios {
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 0%;
  height: 440px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

div#listagem-funcionarios tr {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Deixando o Cabeçalho da tabela (thead) fixo Stackoverflow*/

.table {
  overflow: scroll;
}

div#listagem-funcionarios th {
  position: sticky;
  padding-bottom: -10px;
  z-index: 0;
  background: rgb(47, 70, 116);
  /* box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #ddd, 0 -5px 0 0 #fff; */
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-align: center;
  top: -1.3px;
}

div#modal-incluir-funcionarios {
  color: black;
}

div#modal-alterar-funcionarios {
  color: black;
}

div#modal-header-alterar {
  background-color: rgba(60, 179, 113);
  color: GhostWhite;
}

div#incluir-novo-funcionario {
  background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  padding: 2% 0 0.5% 0;
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Qual o CSS da tabela?

Comment: O CSS não tem algo de muito relevante para a questão do botão. A estilização do botão é feita através de classe do bootstrap. Mas adicionei o código CSS para melhor visualização sua.

Comment: Aqui a solução do Victor não funcionou, por isso pedi que postasse o CSS, porque pode influenciar. Deu certo pra vc por coincidência rs, mas testando com os códigos que vc forneceu, não funciona.

Comment: O único porém é que de forma alguma eu consigo tirar aquele arredondamento das pontas dos botões no Bootstrap. Eu queria que ficasse quadrado. Já tentei de tudo. Border-radius no botão, classe rounded do bootstrap e nada. Pesquisei pela internet e vi nada que fosse exato quanto a isso. Vc acha que cabe abrir uma pergunta aqui sobre isso ou é algo que já tem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o estilo diretamente no HTML, ou criar uma classe para isso. Vou deixar as duas formas.

```
funcionarios += '<td style="text-align: center; padding: 0px"><a style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="btn btn-md btn-success" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-alterar-funcionarios">ALTERAR</a></td>';
```

Para adicionar através de classe. Crie a classe em seu arquivos `.css`.

```
.full-size {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Depois basta adicionar a classe no elemento dinâmico.

```
funcionarios += '<td style="text-align: center; padding: 0px"><a class="btn btn-md btn-success full-size" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-alterar-funcionarios">ALTERAR</a></td>';
```

Comment: Funcionou, Victor. Eu já tinha tentando colocar o height e width 100%. Porém não tinha colocado padding no td. Obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Fico feliz em ter te ajudado.